# Prove or disprove collection is a set

Tags: set-theory

In my set theory exam the following question was proposed:

Determine if, $\{x|\exists \text{y so that }(x,y)=x\}$ is a set or not.(In ZFC)
I think it should not be, but I don't know how to prove it. Any is appreciated :)

Edit: $(x,y)=\{x,\{x,y\}\}$. That is, the ordered pair of x and y

Comment: what do you mean by $(x,y)$ ?

Comment: I'd presume the Kuratowski definition of ordered pair? @dankmemer

Comment: I'll edit it to show what it is, thank you for noticing

Comment: I think it is necessary that $x$ and $y$ belong to sets given a priori, otherwise it would be assuming the existence of the set of all sets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the Axiom of Foundation (aka. Regularity) and the (short) Kuratowskiy definition of ordered pair, this class is the empty set:
If $x=(x,y)=\{x,\{x,y\}\}$, then $x$ contains itself.
We consider $a:=\{x\}$ and note that 
$$ x\cap a=\{x,\{x,y\}\}\cap \{x\}\ni x,$$
hence none of the elements of the non-empty set $a$ is disjoint form $a$, whereas the Axiom of Foundation postulates otherwise.

*Remark:* The result would be the same with any sensible definition of ordered pair as some set construction, for in one way or other, $(x,y)$ will contain $x$ somewhere in itself, though perhaps at a deeper level, which is still forbidden by the Axiom of Foundation.

Comment: The ending remark is inaccurate if you consider [Quine-Rosser ordered pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Quine%E2%80%93Rosser_definition) to be a sensible definition. Under that definition, the collection would contain $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ because $(\mathcal P(\mathbb N),\mathcal P(\mathbb N)) = \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$.

Comment: The Quine-Rosser definition is not only sensible, but even useful sometimes! (well any other definition of pair that does not increase the rank would be just as good to be fair)

Answer (score 1):

Hagen von Eitzen correctly answers that your collection is the empty set in ordinary ZFC (which is assumed to contain an Axiom of Regularity).

However, the Axiom of Regularity is sometimes presented as an "optional" ingredient of ZFC. If your ZFC doesn't contain it (which would arguably a more natural setting for asking about this collection in the first place), then the collection *may or may not* be a set.

It *may be* the empty set, because it might well be that Regularity *just happens* to hold without being required as an axiom.

On the other hand, ZFC$-$Reg allows us to add an [anti-foundation axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aczel%27s_anti-foundation_axiom) without losing consistency. With this axiom, *for each set $A$* we'd be able to find a solution to the equation $x = \{x,\{x,A\}\}$, and all of those solutions would be in your collection. In particular, if your collection was a set, then the union of its union would contain every possible $A$, from which a contradiction would follow by Russell's paradox in the usual way.

So ZFC$-$Reg+AFA (which is equiconsistent with ZFC) proves that your collection is *not* a set.

Comment: Awesome, very helpful

Comment: See Kunen's 1st book, 1st edition, Ch.IV, Exercise 18 (page 148). In particular if $F(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset\}$ and $F(\{\emptyset\})=\emptyset$ and $F(x)=x$ for all other $x$ then the class model $(V,E)$ satisfies all axioms of ZFC except Foundation, and violates Foundation...... Set Theory: An Introduction To Independence Proofs, by K. Kunen.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: It is not quite clear to me which point you intend to make here. Are you perhaps confusing the anti-foundation axiom with the negation of the usual axiom of regularity?

Comment: I was  pointing out (for the proposer) a way to show that if $ZFC^-$ is consistent then it cannot prove Regularity.